# How to display php fetched values in diff textareas?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I was trying to read values from the database. When I clicked on selectpicker and on the basis of EmpId of select picker I will Read names and sal from table and want to display name and sal in the textarea.

I hav only done up to this:
Below is HTML Code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <!--<span class="input-group-addon icon-color"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>-->
    <small>Employee Id</small>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" autocomplete="on" data-live-search="true" id="IEmpId" name="NEmpId" tabindex="1" >
        <option disabled selected>--- Employee Id --- </option>
        <?php  echo fxn_empId(); ?>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <small>Employee Name</small>
        <input type="text" name="NEmpName" id="IEmpName" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Name">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <small>Basic Salary</small>
        <input type="text" name="NBasicSal" id="IBasicSal" class="form-control" placeholder="Basic Salary">
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is JS Code

```
var lcl_switchID    = "1";
$.ajax({
    url     :"script_emp-timiesheet.php",
    method  :"POST",
    data    :{lEmpId:lEmpId, data:lcl_switchID},
    success:function(data){
        if(data=="ok"){
            //fxn_EnableCLR();
        }else{
            alert(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Below is the code for PHP

```
if(isset($_POST["lEmpId"])){
    $lEmpId = $_POST["lEmpId"];
    $Lquery = "SELECT CONCAT(FName,' ', LName) as Name FROM tblempregistration WHERE EmpId = '$LDesgId'";
    $query_result = mysqli_query($conn, $Lquery);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_result) > 0){
        while($row  =   mysqli_fetch_array($Lquery_result)){
            echo '<input type="text" name="NEmpName" value=' .$row[''                                                           
                                                }
```

I dont knw what to do next...

Any suggestions??

Comment: why is your php adding input elements on the page?

Comment: Is there a specific problem, or do you just want to know what to do next?

Comment: *"what to do next... Any suggestions?"*: improve the indentation of your code, make precautions to remove the current vulnerability to SQL injection, fix unclosed square bracket in `.$row[''`, fix missing closing braces (in last block 3 open, only 1 closes), then decide what you want to do next, try it, and if you bump into a particular issue, ask a question about that.

Comment: i made changes as

$lEmpId = $_POST["lEmpId"];
          
           $Lquery = "SELECT FName FROM tblempregistration WHERE EmpId = 'lEmpId'";
           $query_result = mysqli_query($conn, $Lquery);
            
             if(mysqli_num_rows($query_result) > 0){
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)){
               echo '<input type="text" id="IEmpName" value="' .$row['FName'].'"/>';             
             }
But no output in text

Comment: *Where EmpId = '$lEmpId'

I can see the full echo statement with correct name on alert of JQuery..
But the text box is still empty

Comment: you're echoing out some HTML to the response of an ajax request. But then you do nothing with it except echo the string that's returned. There's no code there to append that HTML into your page anywhere. However, a textbox with the same name already exists on the page. It strikes me that surely what you really want to do is have the ajax call return the FName _value_, and then put that value into the existing textbox, rather than returning some HTML for a new textbox?

Comment: How to return multiple values and how to arrange in proper order for adding in HTML tags

Comment: that doesn't answer my question. You can return whatever you like from the ajax request, in whatever order you like, it's up to you, you can echo whatever you like as the response, just write the code in the order you want. You can maybe encode it as JSON to make it structured for jQuery to understand which data item is which. But I was asking about your actual intention.

Comment: 1. You are right, I must use JSON but I have never tried and dont knw
2. My intention is to read name and salary from the table on the bases of some id that I will pass from JQuery to PHP script and there I want to read and if possible i want to display in text boxes through PHP script page and if not then i want to send back to the Jquery page so that I can fill the values in the corresponding text boxes..
But really, I dont know how to do this..
I need guidence and thats why i post my query on this..
Many Thanks

Comment: I have posted an answer which I think will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're echoing out some HTML to the response of an ajax request. But then you do nothing with it except echo the string that's returned. However, a textbox with the same name already exists on the page, so it makes to sense to return the textbox again. What you really want to do is return the data values themselves, and then use JavaScript to place the values into the appropriate existing fields in your page.

I think you can do something like this:

1) On the PHP side, return the database row encoded as JSON:

```
 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Lquery_result)) {
    echo json_encode($row);                                                           
 }
```

2) on the client side, receive the ajax response as JSON, extract the values and place them into the appropriate place in the HTML. In this case, you want to add them as values in textboxes:

```
 var lcl_switchID = "1";
$.ajax({
    url     :"script_emp-timiesheet.php",
    method  :"POST",
    data    :{lEmpId:lEmpId, data:lcl_switchID},
    dataType: "json", //tell jquery to expect JSON back from the server
    success:function(data){
      $("#IEmpName").val(data.FName);
    }
});
```

You can do similar for your other fields. I don't know their exact names so can't give a precise example.

N.B. If the client-side code doesn't work because it can't find the right fields, try debugging to see what the actual structure of the returned data is like. You can write `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` in the "success" function and then check the actual data structure using your browser console, and then adjust the jQuery code to read the data fields accordingly.

Comment: Really, I have learnt new thing from you. It will help me a lot in my all pages I think so..
Really many many Thanks.

Comment: @Partap no problem, happy to help. This is a very common way to do this kind of task so yes it will be something you use a lot in future, I think.

Comment: Share ur email ID, i knw i need the same thing in vice versa.. Means send multiple values from JQuery to PHP and save in single short to database. If i face an issue, i will raise the query i will send the link on ur mail

Comment: @Partap no offence intended, but I don't give my email address out to people I don't know online. If you have a new question, I would happy to answer it if you post it on SO (and so might someone else). If you provide a link to the question here I will check it out ASAP